# Samba 4.7.1 on CentOS 7.5, anonymous share asks for auth

Tags: centos7, samba4

I've got a fresh install of CentOS 7.5 minimal with Samba 4.7.1 on a VM. I've disabled SELinux and added the samba service to firewalld. My goal is to have anonymous and secured shares available.

I've been running in circles for hours, reading a bunch of different tutorials and stackexchange posts trying to figure out why the hell it keeps asking me for a password when I try to access the server when this share should be anonymous and accessible without authentication.

The share is located at `/srv/smbanon`, has its mode set to 777 (I tried 755 and 775 as well), and its owner is `nobody:nobody`, as you can see here:

```
[root@polarserv ~]# ll -a /srv/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root    21 Jun 24 20:20 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root   root   224 Jun 24 18:34 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  2 nobody nobody  18 Jun 24 20:18 smbanon
```

My user mapping file (`/etc/samba/smbusers`) contains only:

```
nobody = guest
```

Here is my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        security = user
        map to guest = bad user
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
        netbios name = polarserv
        ntlm auth = yes

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

        guest account = nobody
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
        log level = 4

#[homes]
#       comment = Home Directories
#       valid users = %S, %D%w%S
#       browseable = No
#       read only = No
#       inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775

[public]
        comment = Public share
        path = /srv/smbanon
        guest ok = yes
        read only = no
        force user = nobody
        force group = nobody
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
```

I've also tried this both with and without `nobody` in the samba user database with no given password.

Any changes I have made to `smb.conf` are vetted by `testparm` and then I cycle the samba services with `systemctl restart smb` and `systemctl restart nmb`.

I'm losing my mind, I see every indicator that the public share should be anonymous yet it's still asking for authentication after a pause when I attempt to access `\\polarserv\` on my Windows 10 machines. What am I missing???

Comment: Is https://serverfault.com/questions/700649/public-share-with-samba4-ad-dc-does-not-work of any help to you?

Comment: @Colt Nope. I'm not on an active directory domain and I already have the `map to guest` directive in my conf.

Comment: If this is Windows 10 issue, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-server-2016. Look around also for many references to problems with Windows 10 "update to 1709" w.r.t. Windows 10 CIFS/SMB Guest access.

Comment: @Colt That... would explain a lot. When I get home I'll mess with my policy settings and see if that solves it. Please consider reposting that information as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Windows 10 issue, see [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-server-2016) about guest access in SMB2 being disabled by default in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update and Windows Server 2016 version 1709. Look around also for many references to problems with Windows 10 "update to 1709" w.r.t. Windows 10 CIFS/SMB Guest access.